# .Net Mongo Driver - Get an Object with path without Find?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I have a MongoDB that is setup like this-

```
product-data
   1234-abcd
       items
           9012-uiop
               name
               price
   5678-efgh
```

I know the full path of the product I want-

`product-data.1234-abcd.items.9012-uiop`

I want to retrieve this nested object without resolving the entire object, and without using find. I've tried a few things-

```
_database.GetCollection<ProductData>("product-data").Find("1234-abcd.items.9012-uiop"); // Thinks the result of Find is ProductData
_database.GetCollection<ProductItem>("product-data.1234-abcd.items.9012-uiop"); // Thinks the result is a collection (naturally)
```

I thought about serializing the second object to json, then deserializing it into the class I expect, but that seemed like a hack.

Given a full path, how can I resolved a nested object in this way using the .Net Mongo Driver?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand, what exat your data structure is, i assume, you do have `ProductData` with string Id and a List of `ProductItem` insisde.

You should call `Find()` if you want to get data from collection. But if you just want to have a certain Item from it, you could project your query result to get only it:

```
ProductItem item = _database.GetCollection<ProductData>("product-data")
                            .Find(x=>x.Id=="1234-abcd")
                            .Project(x=>x.items.First(i=>i.name=="9012-uiop"))
                            .First();
```

Comment: Does this transfer the entire data set or only the 2 items that were requested? (view `First()`). One of my goals is to make this network efficient, otherwise I could just do it all in code.

Comment: this transfer only one ProductItem, with name "9012-uiop"

Comment: Ok. I will try this asap and get back to you. Thanks!